# How the change programmably the password in OrientDB 2.0-rc2?

Tags: orientdb

This works with previous (beta) releases of OrientDB and does not work anymore. So what is the correct way of doing it?

Use case: when creating a new (Document) database I want to change the password of the `admin` user. Code:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx oDb = ...
if (!oDb.exists()) {
        // this will create AND open the database with credentials "admin"/"admin"
        oDb.create();
        // the "admin" user MUST exists, otherwise it is recreated / "repaired" during login, see OSecurityShared. 
        // So we always use 'admin' as name and only change the password
        if ("admin".equals(userName)) {
            OSecurityUser admin = oDb.getUser();
            admin.setPassword(password);
....
```

This will throw an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OImmutableUser.setPassword(OImmutableUser.java:132)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable user was introduced to improve multithreading. You can always get the underlying document.

Try this should work

```
ODocument admin = db.getUser().getDocument();
admin.field("password","newpassword");
admin.save();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works indeed. However ... 1) "Immutable user was introduced to improve multi threading". Where is a reference to this change? 2) How does this improve multi threading if the immutable data can be changed? Explanation of the concept would be nice :)

Comment: I think it was introduced for removing locking to access at the schema and remove possible deadlock and improve speed in high concurrency

Don't know if it was well documented, i've found this
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2895
:D

Comment: Big thanks, understand the "why" now. The "how" is debatable imho, but out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a another solution:

```
// change username and password
ODatabaseDocumentTx database = orientGraphFactory.getDatabase();
OCommandSQL cmd = new OCommandSQL("UPDATE ouser "
  + "SET name = '" + "newName" + "', "
  + "password = '" + "newPassword" + "'"
  + " WHERE name = 'admin'");
database.command(cmd).execute();
database.close();
```

It fires the correct database hooks encoding the password.